# return Validator response in custom format in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using validators as

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|max:10|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }
```

this gives response in format below:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "phone": [
            "The phone has already been taken."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want response as

```
{
"error": 1,
"error_msg": "The phone has already been taken."
}
```

Just one error should show and that too in above format.

Comment: Either you need to write your own validator class or you can assign a new variable which will summarize the value of $validator->errors()

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain and how to summarize the value of $validator->errors()

Comment: if `email` and `phone` both are unique then why not take just one ? is there any specific reason for this ?

Comment: @AnilSangwa here is the laravel validation doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation. You will get the idea how to write custom class or modify output.

Answer (score 1):

For validation to stop after first validation failure, laravel use `bail` check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-bail). So the rules will be like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'bail|required|max:255',
    'phone' => 'bail|required|max:10|unique:users',
    'email' => 'bail|required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6',
]);
```

For formatting error message, you need to do some change in response

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['error'=> 1, 'error_msg' => $validator->errors()->first()], 400);           
}
```

You can create a central place to render the validation error so that it will be consistent validation response format through out the application.

Hope this may help you

Comment: Nice approach. seems logical but gave error as "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\MessageBag as array"

Comment: @AnilSangwa fixed it, updated answer please check it